# Can't find location of libopencv_core.so.3.4.0 even though program is installed and working perfectly

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I installed the openCV library through apt-get. I am trying to install the BGSLibrary and the cmake file tries to find " /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0" The script fails and looking manually the folder isn't there. I have tried searching for it and nothing is turning, infact nothing is turning up for openCV, apart from a folder in usr/local/share which only contains a few cmake files and folders about the haar cascade. I don't even know where openCV is installed even though it is working perfectly.

I am using python 2.7 with openCV 3.4.0

Comment: try doing `locate opencv` in a terminal, it will show all the files path with opencv. In cmake you should use the find_package like `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)` (required for the cmake to fail if not found) this tries to look for a FindOpenCV.cmake file that it is installed during opencv installation....

Comment: In terminal enter: `pkg-config opencv --libs`

Comment: The only hint that you might be using Linux is the mention of `apt-get`. Is it Linux? Did you look in `/usr/lib/` for the OpenCV libraries? That is where `apt` typically installs stuff.

Comment: Assuming this *is* Linux you could try `find /usr/lib* /usr/local/lib* -iname 'libopencv*'` -- some 64 bit distributions put their 64 bit libs under a `lib64` subdirectory and reserve the `lib` directory for 32 bit binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its important to have your cMake report (outputlog file) up to the error reporting included into your question without it a black box is presented. Anyhow.. a shot for the bow below.

Look into your cMake output/log for:

> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:123456: recipe for target 'modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all' failed.

followed by something like:

> ```
> make[1]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/opencv32018MMDD7-12345-abcdefg/opencv-3.4.0/>OS system <'
> Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

Then see if below is showing up:

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/libpython2.7.so', needed by 'lib/cv2.so'.  Stop.

If so you need to check  CMake/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake
 file what to do. Github check [here at L30-L35](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake#L30-L35) in the cMake pythonlib file what to do exactly to set python lib path correctly... to prevent a cascade of underlying errors.

...but as no cMake output/log file was given and OS remains undetermined ..its a shot in the dark. Nevertheless, I hope it points you in the right direction how to fix it.